# Symfony Doctrine lazy loading the second child from OneToOne relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have a very weird question about tweaking and minimizing the database calls by my Symfony application.
I have 3 related entities, namely (for example) `Book`, `Author` and `Publisher` and they are related by `OneToOne` relations as shown bellow:

```
Book
{
    /**
     * @var Author
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Author", mappedBy="book", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $author;
}
```

```
Author
{
    /**
     * @var Book
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Book", inversedBy="author", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $book;

    /**
     * @var Publisher|null
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Publisher", mappedBy="author", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $publisher;
}
```

```
Publisher
{
    /**
     * @var Author
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Author", inversedBy="publisher")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;
}
```

Now, if I make a call to fetch all the database records of books as bellow:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Author')->findAll();
```

it makes only 1 call to the database, but when I try to make the same call for the `Book` entity in the same way:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Book')->findAll();
```

it leads to thousand calls.
From my debugging what I have found is, it makes one call to get all the books but then make a several calls (2558 calls in my case) trying to find the `Author->Publisher` relations. This is a great waste of memory, processor, time and performance.

To dig a bit deeper, it seems like (though I am not 100% sure), it is trying to `HydrateAllData` and makes the unwanted calls here to the database.

Can anybody help me to figure out what is actually happening and how to stop/tweak it please?

Comment: this is most likely caused by the *ownership* of the one-to-one relation (meaning: one entity always knows the id of the "other side", and the "other side" doesn't, thus needs an additional query). What you can do is to *eagerly fetch*  the relations (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_onetoone), especially if you always need the author.

Comment: @Jakumi but I am confused as, when I make a `findAll()` on `Author`, this relation is not fetched. It is only fetched when I make the `findAll()` on `Book` entity, where as, `Book` and `Publisher` is not directly connected (connected via `Author`).

Comment: I assume, since the author is the owner of the author-book relationship, loading books will somehow trigger Author to be initialized (in contrast to having some of its relations be lazy loaded). I don't know why this is, since I'm not particularly a doctrine expert, but declaring the author-publisher relation as `fetch="EAGER"` on the author entity will most likely reduce the amount of queries, though I'm not absolutely certain.

Comment: @Jakumi Unfortunately nothing happens what so ever fetching methodology I define in the author-publisher relation. But to mention the strange thing again, when fetching all the `Author` entities, the `Publisher` is not fetched.

Comment: okay, in theory that's not strange, because doctrine by default always lazy-loads its relations. that is, instead of an *actual* Author class object, you get a proxy object that will load the lazy loaded relations on access. (which often is, what the user should and would want). meaning, as soon as you request some $author->publisher, it will load that publisher by some means.

Comment: @Jakumi You are absolutely right. But I am never touching the relations. I am fetching them and making a dump of the results. So, when I fetch and make a dump of `Author`, the lazy loading is working there, but when I fetch all `Book`, the lazy loading is not working. In neither of the cases, I am trying to retrieve the `Publisher` entity. Neither by `$author->getPublisher()` nor by `$book->getAuthor()->getPublisher()`.

Comment: is your code visible somewhere on github or something, because I feel like just blindly guessing and the actual complete code of controller, repositories (if any) and entities and possible configurations might help ...

Comment: @Jakumi Unfortunately not. But I am trying to optimise it now by changing the direction of the relation. I know it is not a very good or clean idea but it might save me for now.

Comment: if your intention is to export data for some api or dump, I would rather suggest that you make a custom DQL query. In that way you could get away with only a single query...